# Long string in ListView's items in Android

Tags: android, string, listview, long-integer

My question is concerned to the next: my android app gets rather long strings from internet and places their into a ListView. Herewith current behaviour of ListView is such that strings are inserted in items completely that I see two or even more string in item. Can I change the ListView's behavior in such way to cause it to insert string in ListView something like that

```
"Long string is rather...."
"Long string is rather...."
```

changing the end of string, that doesn't fit to items, to three dots ?

Comment: I believe this answers your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds

Comment: Thanks for link, but it my case the answer is more simplier - I must use android:singleLine="true".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set this to your TextView used as a row in List:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do that.
**Fix the layout_width of the textView in XML property** of the textView.

Say:

```
 <TextView
       android:id="@+id/text"
       android:layout_width="120dip"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="text from server"
        android:singleLine="true"
       android:textColor="#ffffff"
       ></TextView>
```

In this way the text will be get adjust into that width accordingly (For example "Long string is rather...")

Answer (score 0):

You can make it scroll if you use focus, however; with a listview this is going to be difficult because when should you request focus? Specifically you need to shrink your strings, simple a that. And set a max length on your ListView Items. So that they cap out at a certain length.